# Solve ODE for real free falling: $y(x)^2\cdot y^{\prime\prime}(x)]=4\cdot 10^{14}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, classical-mechanics, mathematica, stability-in-odes

I am trying to describe the position of a free falling ball by gravity:
if

- $x$ is the time in seconds,
- $y$ is the position of the falling ball,
- $y^{\prime\prime}(x)$ is its acceleration

then
$$
F=G\frac{M_1\cdot M_2}{y(x)^2}=M_2 y^{\prime\prime}(x), 
$$ 
and since for the Earth $G\cdot M_1=4\cdot10^14$, we just need to solve for $y$ the following equation: 
$$
y(x)^2\cdot y^{\prime\prime}(x)=4\cdot 10^{14}
$$
I have put it in Mathematica by using the following command:

> DSolve[{y[x]^2*y''[x]==4*10^14},y[x],x]

but I got no answer: how can I solve for $y$ and plot it?

Comment: Because it likely has no closed-form solution and you need to resort to numerical methods. Did you try that to see what the solutions look like?

Comment: Nonlinear ODEs are not generally solvable in any meaningful way. You should be able to plot the solution with NDSolve in Mathematica.

Comment: I have put this in mathematica but get no graf:  NDSolve[{y[x]^2*y''[x] == 4*10^14, y[0] == 6371019, 
  y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 25}]

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen that differential equation for a free-falling object OP. I had seen $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = g - c\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ where $c$ is a positive constant; the  $c\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ reflects air resistance. As in, the object's acceleration down lowers and lowers as it approaches a terminal velocity.

Comment: here I have made it accurate in a vacuum so the force is changing with distance by F=Gm1m2/r^2

Comment: you right JCA. my goal is to understand how gravity work in the most fundamental way. My theory explains everything very profoundly including gravity, watch my video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omOlPH_4G5U

Comment: Thanks @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I see it now, OP is trying to model the acceleration curve of an object falling into the center of earth--where the acceleration is proportional to $\frac{1}{r^2}$ where $r$ is the distance from the center

Comment: Since gravity is an attractive force, don't you need a minus-sign on one side of your equation?

Comment: yes I need a minus sign you right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an analytic solution. The ODE and initial conditions are:

$$y'' = -\frac{G M_1}{y^2(t)}$$
$$y(0)=y_0$$
$$y'(0)=v_0$$

Define dimensionless variables as follows:
$$t_0 \equiv \sqrt{\frac{y_0^3}{2 G M_1}}$$
$$T \equiv t/t_0$$
$$Y \equiv y/y_0$$
$$V_0 \equiv v_0 t_0/y_0$$

Then the ODE and initial conditions can be written as:
$$2Y'' = -\frac{1}{Y^2}$$
$$Y(0) = 1$$
$$Y'(0) = V_0$$

To solve, multiply both sides of the ODE by $Y'$ and integrate
$$2 Y' Y'' = -\frac{Y'}{Y^2}$$
$$ Y'^2 = C_1 + \frac{1}{Y}$$

Use the initial condition to eliminate $C_1$ then solve for $Y'$
$$ V_0^2 = C_1 + 1$$
$$ Y'^2 - V_0^2 = \frac{1}{Y} - 1$$
$$ Y' = \pm\sqrt{V_0^2 + \frac{1}{Y} - 1}= \pm\sqrt{W + \frac{1}{Y}}$$

where $W \equiv V_0^2 - 1$ and the sign is chosen to match $sign(v_0)$. Separating variables gives
$$dT = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{W+\frac{1}{Y}}} = \pm \frac{Y}{\sqrt{WY^2+Y}} dY$$

**Case 1**. When $W<0$ then $M_2$ has a velocity less than the escape velocity; if  $M_2$ is initially rising ($v_0>0$), gravity will decelerate it enough to cause it to reverse direction and fall.

To integrate, we will manipulate the term under the radical to a form $1-z^2$. Multiply top and bottom of the RHS by $2\sqrt{-W}$

$$dT = \pm \frac{2\sqrt{-W}Y}{\sqrt{-4W^2Y^2-4WY}}dY = \pm \frac{2\sqrt{-W}Y}{\sqrt{-4W^2Y^2-4WY-1+1}}dY = \pm \frac{2\sqrt{-W}Y}{\sqrt{1-(1+2WY)^2}} dY$$

Now introduce $U\equiv 1+2WY; dU=2W dY$. Then

$$2 (-W)^{3/2} dT = \pm \frac{U-1}{\sqrt{1-U^2}} dU$$

Integrate

$$2 (-W)^{3/2} T = C_2 \pm \left[-\sqrt{1-U^2} - \arcsin{U} \right]$$
$$2 (-W)^{3/2} T = C_2 \pm \left[-\sqrt{1-(1+2WY)^2} - \arcsin(1+2WY) \right]$$

From the initial conditions
$$0 = C_2 \pm \left[-\sqrt{1-(1+2W)^2} - \arcsin(1+2W) \right]$$

Subtracting and rearranging gives
$$ T = \pm \left[-\left(\sqrt{\frac{Y^2}{W}+\frac{Y}{(-W)^2}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{W}+\frac{1}{(-W)^2}}\right) - \frac{\arcsin(1+2WY) - \arcsin(1+2W)}{2 (-W)^{3/2}} \right]$$

If the motion is initially upward $M_2$ will rise to a height $Y=-1/W$ before beginning to fall.

For the *special case* when $M_2$ is initially stationary, $v_0=0$, $W=-1$ so
$$ T = \left[\left(\sqrt{-Y^2+Y}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\arcsin(1-2Y) - \arcsin(-1)\right) \right]$$

**Case 2**. When $W>0$ then $M_2$ has a velocity greater than the escape velocity; if  $M_2$ is initially rising ($v_0>0$), it will decelerate but never fall.

The steps for solving this are to Case 1, but the integral includes $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ instead of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$. After integration the result is

$$ T = \pm \left[\left(\sqrt{\frac{Y^2}{W}+\frac{Y}{W^2}} - \sqrt{\frac{1}{W}+\frac{1}{W^2}}\right) - \frac{1}{2 W^{3/2}} \ln{\frac{1+2WY + 2\sqrt{W^2Y^2+WY}}{1+2W + 2\sqrt{W^2+W}}} \right]$$

**Case 3**. The solution for the degenerate case $W=0$ is straightforward.
$$dT = \pm \sqrt{Y} dY$$
$$T = C_2 \pm \frac{2}{3}{Y}^{3/2}$$

Initial condition
$$0 = C_2 \pm \frac{2}{3}$$
$$T = \pm \frac{2}{3}\left[{Y}^{3/2} - 1 \right]$$

Hope that helps.

Comment: so what is y(t)?

Answer (score 2):

This nonlinear ODE does not appear to have a closed-form solution.

Since you are using Mathematica, you can use numerical methods to solve it. We have

```
   s = NDSolve[{y[x]^2*y''[x] == 4*10^14, y[0] == 6371019, y'[0] == 0}, 
    y, {x, 0, 25}]

   Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The plot is

[image]

We can also use the following to plot $y(x), y'(x), y''(x)$

```
    Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x], y''[x]} /. s], {x, 0, 25}, 
     PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

We get

[image]